# For every 10th in a array.count(1)

Tags: python, arrays, count

So I got a array of die rolls 1 to 6.

So I count the times 1 runs in the array with .count, but I also have to print something for every time that count passes a 10. So if I roll 100 times and I get 23 rolls of 1, I want it to show a * for each 10 in it.

The code so far is:

```
import random

die_rolls = []

maxsize = int(input("What is the maximum die rolls: ")) + 1

for num in range(1,maxsize):
    die_random = random.randint (1,6)
    die_rolls.append(die_random)

print(str(maxsize-1) + " total rolls.")
percent_one = die_rolls.count(1) / maxsize *100

print("1: " + "[" + str(die_rolls.count(1)) + " |", "{:.1f}".format(percent_one) + "%]")

total=sum(die_rolls)
print(total)
```

and I get:

```
What is the maximum die rolls: 100
100 total rolls.
1: [21 | 20.8%]
329
```

I need it to look like:

```
What is the maximum die rolls: 100
100 total rolls.
1: ** [21 | 20.8%]
329
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Clearly there must be something in between `"1: " + "["`. Did you try anything? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: By the way, `range(1,maxsize)` will only get you `maxsize - 1` rolls. Simply use `range(maxsize)` instead.

Comment: Sorry it's confusing mkrieger1, I hadn't added anything between `"1: " + "["` because I didn't know what to add, hence why I put what it looked like, and what it should have to show what should be there, and thanks for the `range(maxsize)` tip, due to complications had to team up with someone else who wrote this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
stars = "*" * (die_rolls.count(1) // 10)
print("1: " + stars + " [" + str(die_rolls.count(1)) + " |", "{:.1f}".format(percent_one) + "%]")
```

The // operator performs integer division, so 19//10 = 1, 20//10 = 2, 21//10 = 2, etc.

Writing "*" * 2 makes Python repeat the string "*" twice.

Comment: Thanks for this completely forgot about integer division.

Answer (score 0):

```
stars = '*' * (die_rolls.count(1) // 10)  # count number of stars
print('1: {0} [{1} | {2:.1f}%]'.format(stars, die_rolls.count(1), percent_one))
```

EDIT: as suggested by @Ev.Kounis save die_rolls.count(1) to a variable.
E.g. `count_one = die_rolls.count(1)`

Comment: I would save the `die_rolls.count(1)`. You are counting the elements twice like that and if `die_rolls` gets big enough, this would make a difference.